# Get div to scroll if height exceeds xx% with another dependent div occupying remaining height of page.

Tags: css, layout, scroll, height, grid-layout

I am trying to create a page that has 6 vertically stacked divs (from top to bottom: A,B,C,D,E,and F). Divs B,C,D, and F all use static pixel sizing for height (only divs A and E are of variable height).  Div E's content can be of any length - its height should be between 10% to 40% of the screen height and should scroll if there's too much content. I've hacked at a few solutions, but I'm stuck: https://codepen.io/RiverTaig/pen/zLLEeG Here's the goal:

[image]

The CSS for div E seems to do nothing useful.

```
#E {
  min-height: 10%;
  max-height: 40%;
}
```

I'm pretty new to working with Grid for flex sizing in CSS - perhaps that the best way to go for this problem? I tried that approach, but failed.

Comment: You are almost good, missing only `html{height:100%;} wrapper {height:100%}`

Comment: I got this to work using table sizing. I'm not sure if that's a good approach or not for general responsive design, but it works: https://codepen.io/RiverTaig/pen/djjZdm